# How do I combine an "if" and a "while loop" statement together?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, while-loop

New to shell scripting and I want to test to see if the variables I created are valid directories and if not send the user into a while loop to enter the directory and only allow exit when a valid directory is entered.

So far this is what my script looks like:

```
~/bin/bash
source_dir="$1"
dest_dir="$2"

mkdir /#HOME/$source_dir
mkdir /#HOME$dest_dir


if [ -d  "$source_dir" ]
then
        echo "$source_dir is a valid directory"
fi

while [[ ! -d "$source_dir" ]]
do
        echo "Please enter a valid directory"
        read source_dir
done
```

Is there any way to combine these into a single statement?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach. I would however consider the intention of your code better understandable, if you moved the *while* inside the else branch of the *if*. This is however a general question of programming style and not related to shell scripting.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` code will *never* execute if the directory is valid.  Therefore just move the `echo "$source_dir is a valid directory"` after the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
source_dir="$1"
dest_dir="$2"

mkdir "$HOME/$source_dir"
mkdir "$HOME/$dest_dir"

until [[ -d "$source_dir" ]]
do
        read -p "Please enter a valid directory" source_dir
done
echo "$source_dir is a valid directory"
```

Notes:

- a few code typos were fixed, e.g. `/#HOME$dest_dir` should be `"$HOME/$dest_dir"`.
- any `while !` can be shortened to `until`.

The above code lacks a few things:

- It tries create a *new* dir, then if that fails, has the user enter an already *existing* directory.  It might be better to let the user *create* a new directory, but only if it doesn't already exist.
- It would be better to check if `$dest_dir` exists.

Here's a more thorough approach using a shell function:

```
#!/bin/bash
untilmkdir () 
{ 
    d="$1";
    until mkdir "$d" ; do
        read -p "Please enter a valid directory: " d
        [ -d "$d" ] && break
    done;
    echo "$d is a valid directory" 1>&2
    echo "$d"
}

source_dir=$(untilmkdir "$HOME/$1")
dest_dir=$(untilmkdir "$HOME/$2")
```

Notes:

- The prompts in `untilmkdir` are printed to *stderr*.
- The name of whatever directory `untilmkdir` creates is printed to *stdout*.
- Having `untilmkdir` print to both *stderr* and *stdout* allows storing the successfully created name to a variable.

Comment: I think this is the point. The loop **should** not be executed if the directory already exists initially.

Comment: @user1934428, `! mkdir foo` returns *true* only if *foo* does not exist, therefore the loop never executes unless it's needed.   A false `if` and a false `while` are functionally equivalent here.

Comment: Little known fact: there is an `until` loop defined by POSIX. `until mkdir "$HOME/$source_dir" 2> /dev/null; do`

Comment: @chepner, Better.  Thanks!

Comment: @agc: I should have been more explicit in my argument: Following the logic of the original program, the message *... is a valid directory* should be printed **only** if the directory in $1 either already existed initially or could at least be created successfully. Otherwise, the loop should be entered, with all the prompts and so on. That's why I would find it more natural to use an *if ... else .... fi* and put the loop into the *else* part. Of course there **are** some oddities in the original program. Why is it created under `/$HOME` and not under `$HOME`? Why `mkdir` and not `mkdir -p`?

Comment: @user1934428, Thanks, I'd missed the `/` before `$HOME`.  Another curiosity is that there's no such safety check for `$dest_dir`, and two such checks might as well be a function.  The value of `mkdir -p` seems less obvious... I'd worry the user might enter something excessive.

Comment: I implicitly assumed that there will perhaps be a check for $dest_dir in the same way, and the OP poster didn't see a need to repeat this in his code. What now confuses me more, is that OP's code has been edited. It's now complete garbage, with #HOME and, in the first line, a funny ~/bin/bash. No idea which way this is supposed to go ....